# How can I fit a video to a certain size, but don't upscale it with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to fit videos to 640x360 (the maximum my phone's player can handle), while also preserving aspect ratio, but I also want the video to be unchanged if it is smaller than 640x360 (no point in up-scaling it after all).

Is there a way to get this behavior using ffmpeg's command line?

Comment: I don't think this can be done solely in ffmpeg, but if you're willing to script it, it can definitely be done.

Comment: I've already scripted it, but I wanted to clean up my code in case it' s not needed.

Comment: It's probably possible with a scale filter that uses functions such as `min(…)` but most definitely easier with a simple script that parses the dimensions. See my command here for an example of what can be done: http://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player/547406#547406

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With newer ffmpeg versions, you can use the `scale` filter's `force_original_aspect_ratio` option. For example, to fit a video into 1280×720, without upscaling (see [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/48078) for more info):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" output.mp4
```

Here, the `scale` filter scales to 1280×720 if the input video is larger than that. If it is smaller, it will not be upscaled. The `pad` filter is necessary to bring the output video to 1280×720, in case its aspect ratio or size differs from the target size.

---

With older ffmpeg versions, there is a somewhat hacky workaround.
First, define the width, height and aspect ratio of your output. This will save us some typing.

```
width=640; height=360
aspect=$( bc <<< "scale=3; $width / $height") # <= floating point division
```

Now, let's apply the super complex filter command that [Jim Worrall wrote](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-December/003656.html):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale = min(1\,gt(iw\,$width)+gt(ih\,$height)) * (gte(a\,$aspect)*$width + \
lt(a\,$aspect)*(($height*iw)/ih)) + not(min(1\,gt(iw\,$width)+gt(ih\,$height)))*iw : \
min(1\,gt(iw\,$width)+gt(ih\,$height)) * (lte(a\,$aspect)*$height + \
gt(a\,$aspect)*(($width*ih)/iw)) + not(min(1\,gt(iw\,$width)+gt(ih\,$height)))*ih" \
output.mp4
```

I won't really go into explaining what this all does, but basically you can feed it any video, and it will only downscale, not upscale. If you're up for it you can dissect the filter into its individual expressions. It might be possible to shorten this, but it works like that as well.

Comment: +1 but that is a truly horrific command :P

Comment: I know right? I spent ten minutes trying to break it into logical parts and then inserting some values but I gave up. It's a little old and maybe it'd be possible to write it much more concisely than this though.

Comment: I really don't understand why the single quotes are where they are: `scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)'`

Comment: @maf-soft Because the comma is usually used by ffmpeg to separate filters in a filter chain (in the above example, between `scale` and `pad`). By quoting it, ffmpeg will not interpret the comma that way, but use it as part of the first option passed to `scale`, which is `min(1280,iw)`.

Comment: I was more wondering about the `min'(` - but now I found out that you don't even need matching pairs of quotes, it is enough to have one single quote _anywhere_ before the first comma, like in `scale=min(12'80,iw):min(720,ih)` :) - doesn't make much sense, but works. A second quote is only needed somewhere before a regular comma if you need one, like before `,pad`.

Comment: @maf-soft In principle, yes, you can place those anywhere, but that kind of quoting does not make sense to me at all – at least it makes the command very hard to read.

Answer (score 21):

A more readable version can look like follows:

```
-filter_complex "scale=iw*min(1\,min(640/iw\,360/ih)):-1"
```

640/iw is the horizontal scaling factor and 360/ih is the vertical scaling factor

You want to fit the scaled image inside the output box and keep the (storage) aspect ratio. You do this by selecting the smallest scaling factor with the minimum function:
min(640/iw, 360/ih)

You want to prevent any upscaling (i.e. a scaling factor > 1.0) so you add another minimum function:
min(1, min(640/iw, 360/ih))

Next step is to calculate the output resolution by multiplying the scaling-factor with input-width and input-height:
output-width = iw * min(1, min(640/iw, 360/ih))
output-height = ih * min(1, min(640/iw, 360/ih))

Last step is to construct the filter command. There is no need to specify the output-height, you can specify -1 and ffmpeg will keep the aspect ratio by applying the same scaling factor as for the width.

Comment: A+ Works out of the box. Selected answer's solution did *not* preserve aspect ratio. It squeezed the frames.

Comment: FYI for everyone else looking into this, if you run into issues where you get 'height not divisible by 2' do this one instead: ceil(iw*min(1\,min(640/iw\,360/ih))/2)*2:-1, it adds 1px if the concerning edge is odd.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem too, but solved by fitting the video in a square 640x640 (because of vertical videos made with smartphones).

So using *immerzi* logic and some research I end up with this:

```
-vf "scale=iw*min(1\,if(gt(iw\,ih)\,640/iw\,(640*sar)/ih)):(floor((ow/dar)/2))*2"
```

the last part is for having a height divisible by 2 that is need by many encoders.