# Using conditional filters in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, conditional-statements

It blew my mind when I recently came across something new about FFmpeg despite having used it for years - the fact that it comes out of the box with advanced conditionals like `if` statements and `lt`/`gt` for filters. To me this has to be its most underrated feature, or at least it would be if the documentation mentioned anything about them and how they worked.

I want to take advantage of them in my FFmpeg scripts to upscale videos intelligently based on their height: if a video's height is less than 720 pixels, to upscale it to `-1:720` (that is, a height of 720 and a proportional width that maintains its aspect ratio), and to leave it unchanged if it's 720 pixels or greater. What would a `scale` filter to do this with `if` and `lt`/`gt` look like?

Comment: Some of this (the functions) is covered in the docs here: ( https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation ). What is lacking is how/where the variables are set for the filters themselves. I know that `iw` and `ih` are input widht and input height for the `scale` filter, but I don't see how people know this on a quick scan of the documentation. Admittedly, I have not read the docs "cover to cover"

Comment: I take that back: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Options-1 has constants listed for scale. That doc covers a wide array of filters.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/566998/how-can-i-fit-a-video-to-a-certain-size-but-dont-upscale-it-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @Yorik Great find, I had searched the docs for everything but "expression". I have come across that before but its use of the `pad` filter worries me because I'm not sure from *slhck*'s wording in what situation the padding is actually applied, and it sounds like it will end up either padding or cropping my videos.

Comment: I would take a very small subset of vids, make some very short clips, suitable to rapidly test the decision tree, and then run them through. The linked stack Q is only one of many to examine as examples. Padding could also be addressed using evaluation.

Comment: @Yorik I just took a closer look at that example from *slhck* and it does what most other examples do - scale down if higher than a certain width and height - which is very different to what I'm trying to do here. I would also actually like to know how to accomplish it with `if` and `lt` and whether they would make for a simpler command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *[max](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)*:

> `max(x, y)`
> Return the maximum between `x` and `y`.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=-1:'max(720,ih)'" output
```

> If I wanted to replace the `-1` with a `$width` variable in my script, would there be a way to ensure that `$width` is only acted on when the right side (i.e. height) is also upscaled?

Example using *if* and *lt*:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale='if(lt(ih,720),$width,iw)':'max(720,ih)'" output
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity, I had a feeling `max` might do what I want but I didn't think it would be this simple. If I wanted to replace the `-1` with a `$width` variable in my script, would there be a way to ensure that `$width` is only acted on when the right side (i.e. height) is also upscaled?

Comment: @HashimAziz One method is to use *if* with *lt* / *lte* or *gt* / *gte*.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. To clarify, are the two versions with `-1` and `if...$width` equivalent? So the `-1` solution should also only upscale when the right side is upscaled?

Comment: @HashimAziz *To clarify, are the two versions with -1 and if...$width equivalent?* Sorry, I don't understand this question. `$width` can be any arbitrary value. `-1` is determined by the other dimension and aspect. *So the -1 solution should also only upscale when the right side is upscaled?* Yes.