# Video padding using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying the padding option using ffmpeg, but I am getting an error.

I am following [this tutorial](http://linuxers.org/tutorial/how-pad-videos-using-ffmpeg). Here's the error:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-11-13-129af66 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Nov 13 2013 16:40:26 with gcc 4.4.3 (GCC)
configuration: --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --prefix=../build --sysroot=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --extra-cflags=' -I/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -I/Users/sunitha/Downloads/full_ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android/libmp3lame/include -DANDROID -marm -march=armv6 ' --extra-ldflags=' -L/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/Users/sunitha/Downloads/full_ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android/libmp3lame/lib' --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avfilter --enable-decoders --enable-demuxers --enable-encoders --enable-filters --enable-indevs --enable-network --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-swscale --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100  
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102  
libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102  
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100  
libavfilter     3. 80.100 /  3. 80.100  
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100  
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102  
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Unrecognized option 'padtop 120'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: You might want to look at this https://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try it this way instead:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "pad=width=640:height=480:x=0:y=120:color=black" output.avi
```

The video filter syntax is the new way to use padding. Here the video output width and height are 640x480 and the image is placed 120 pixels from top, 0 pixels from left. To work out your exact dimensions, just apply the same principles.

See the [`pad` video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) documentation for more details.

Comment: Rajib i might be a stupid question, but i need to add also for portrait video so how can i do it. Is it works for only landscape. I tried it for portrait but not happening properly.

Comment: @Gururaj You should post the exact dimensions of the "portrait" video, the exact dimensions of the output ("frame") video. I'm not sure, but I think you can add it to your main question itself by editing.

Comment: Rajib i have a portrait video of dimension 400*800 i want to add padding to make this as a square video. What command I should pass?. Please provide sample command for this particular dimension video.

Comment: @Gururaj only a guess but I think the vf parameter for you (assuming you want it horizontally centered with black padding on the sides) would be: `-vf "pad=width=800:height=800:x=200:y=0:color=black"` (y=200 because that's the extra 400 px padding / 2)