# FFmpeg - scale and pad

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video that I want to upscale but I don't want to lose the aspect ratio of the original video.

My source file resolution is `864 x 692` and I want to upscale it to `1280 x 720`

I found this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/547406) but honestly I could not understand how to do it.

If you can help me build a ffmpeg command that is suited to my case it will really help me.

Thank you

Update
I used this guide and I got close to whatever I wanted to do
https://superuser.com/a/690211

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have two main options to make it fit after using [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale): [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) or [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop). Take a look at these examples and the documentation for each filter.

## pad

This will pillarbox the image.

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=-1:720,pad=1280:ih:(ow-iw)/2" output
```

A more generic command that will work for all input file aspect ratios will use `force_original_aspect_ratio=1` as an option to `scale`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" output
```

## crop

This will cut off the top and bottom.

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=1280:-1,crop=iw:720" output
```

A more generic command that will work for all input file aspect ratios will use `force_original_aspect_ratio=2` as an option to `scale`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=2,crop=1280:720" output
```

---

## Use your player

If you don't want to bother with re-encoding, then any player worth using should allow you to do this upon playback. Example using `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -vf "scale=-1:720,pad=1280:ih:(ow-iw)/2" input
```

Or see "Video Effects" in VLC.

Comment: This is a great answer,  I especially like that it includes the arguments to `pad` to make images of different sizes all centered, instead of in the upper left corner :)

Comment: What a great answer, the generic pad command was exactly what I was looking for!