# ffmpeg pattern_type glob doesn't accept '*' wildcard

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multiple images which I want to convert into a video.

Contents of my directory 'images':

```
foo.png
bar.jpg
foobar.jpeg
...
```

So I wanted to execute a simple ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "images/*"  video.mp4
```

This doesn't work because:

```
[in#0 @ 0x594919f55040] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file images/*.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory
```

Is there to generate it like this (or similar)?

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "images/*.[png|jpg|jpeg]"  video.mp4
```

Comment: Mixing PNG and JPEG images is not supported with [image2](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/image2-2.htm.gz) demuxer `.jpg` and `. jpeg` suppose to work using the following syntax: `ffmpeg -y -c:v mjpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i "*.[jpg][jpeg]*" video.mp4`. Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42676472/4926757). The answer suggests converting all images to PNG first. There is also a solution using concat demuxer with `-reinit_filter 0` as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1661740/635712). I would have used a Python script.