# How to convert jpeg images in a slideshow video with transition effects

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, avidemux

I have some jpeg images and I want to create a slideshow video. I want a crossfade between images.

What I tried :

Mencoder : I did this command `mencoder mf://*.jpg -mf fps=25:type=jpg -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=1200:threads=2 -o outputfile.mkv`. It put my images one after another and I don't know how to specify the time and an effect. Furthermore, it seems to be an old project.

oggSlideshow : It works but it's very long. I used this command `oggSlideshow image*.jpg -t cf -l 2 -s 1200x800  -f 16 -o out2.ogv`. It takes 2 minutes for 15 images. The result is near of what I want.

ffmpeg : I can do a fade effect between images but not a crossfade.

Avidemux : I don't know if it's possible to do what I want.

Any clue?

**Edit 1**

I want a cross fade and not a fadein/out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](http://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg)

Comment: This is fadeIn/out I and I prefer a cross fade.

Comment: Answer updated. Now it's a duplicate.

Comment: It works but it seems to be a little bit complicated. I will try to make a script.