# Convert multiple images to a gif with cross-dissolve

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, gif

I've found both of these amazing answers on Superuser: one to convert a series of images to a video with cross-dissolves between them, and another to convert a video to a high-quality gif. My follow-up question to both of those is, how can I do this in one command, for multiple images (could be 3 images, or could be 20).

@LordNeckbeard and other ffmpeg superusers, can you help me out?

Here's the answers that have helped so far:

Images to Video with cross-dissolve:
https://superuser.com/a/834035/523746

Video to Gif:
https://superuser.com/a/556031/523746