# How to pass arguments to blend filter FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I am trying to merge 5 images and create a blinking video after combining them.I have successfully applied fade-in fade-out effect for them. FFMPEG is still fairly new to me.

Here is the command I have executed:

```
"-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_001.jpg " +
"-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_002.jpg " +
"-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_003.jpg " +
"-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_004.jpg " +
"-loop 1 -i "+path+"images_005.jpg " +
"-filter_complex " +
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v];" +
"[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v];" +
"[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b3v];" +
"[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b4v];" +
"[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v][4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] "+path+"out.mp4"
```

on Executing this command the process keeps running forever. There is my screenshot of that thing :

[image]

I know I am missing something silly; As i am new in `ffmpeg` it would be great if I could get some knowledge of where I am going wrong here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each `-loop 1`, insert `-t x` where x is duration in seconds.

Comment: i will try and let you know..!!

Comment: `-t no such file or directory` getting this error..!!

Comment: Verify the syntax. It should be `"-loop 1 -t 1 -i "`

Comment: It worked like a charm.. Thank you so much.. You are god..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for blend doesn't make sense to me. What you want to do?
Blend does something like this for each pixel: pixel component = function(pixel component of A input, pixel component of B input).
So what your function should do? It could do (A + B) / 2 which is very simple case....

Comment: It doesn't making sense then see this : http://superuser.com/a/834035/595224