# How to create a video with slide transition from images using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow

Have two or three images, want to create slide left , slide up , slide right and slide down transitions using ffmpeg

Fade in and out i found from the link [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg)

Comment: @Mulvya Are above animations possible? I am also looking for same.Thanks.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  Do you have any suggestions for same ? Thanks.