# ffmpeg: scale images prior to crossfade blend using filter_complex

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I'm attempting to create an mp4 of one image crossfaded into another using the blend filter and `filter_complex`, as illustrated in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg/834035#answer-834035).

But I also want to scale both images to 480p prior to blending.  Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i field.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i island.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=hd480[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=hd480[v1]; \
 [v1][v0]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v]; \
 [v0][b1v][v1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" -threads 0 -preset ultrafast -y out.mp4
```

However it seems concat fails with the following output:

```
Input #0, image2, from 'field.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 409918 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4000x2000 [SAR 72:72 DAR 2:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, image2, from 'island.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 252593 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4000x2000 [SAR 72:72 DAR 2:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x57425e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x577e4a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_concat_3 @ 0x59c1c20] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 852x480, SAR 80:71) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (4000x2000, SAR 72:72)
[Parsed_concat_3 @ 0x59c1c20] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_3
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Both images are 4000x2000px, [field.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsNfi.jpg) and [island.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz1Ia.jpg).

Really appreciate any help.  Using a recent nightly build:

```
ffmpeg version N-81188-gcebad64-static
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i field.jpg -loop 1 -t 1 -i island.jpg  
       -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:480,split[v0][cv0];
                        [1:v]scale=-2:480,split[v1][cv1];
 [v1][v0]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v];
 [cv0][b1v][cv1]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" -threads 0 -preset ultrafast -y out.mp4
```

Input pads generated inside a filter complex can only be consumed once. So, I put a split to generate one copy for the concat. I also changed the scale to `-2:480` to preserve the aspect ratio. You can revert it to `hd480` but web players that don't respect aspect ratio flags will show the video distorted.