# How to add audio input in FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

In a simple slideshow (taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg)):

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input0.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input4.png \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [4:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

How can I add audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input0.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input4.png \
             -i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [4:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 5:a out.mp4
```

You may want to add `-shortest` or `-t 25` if the audio is longer.