# No file output produced by melt

Tags: linux, video, melt

I am using [`melt`](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/) (based on [MLT](https://www.mltframework.org/)) to produce a gif with transitions from three images, as per [Lordneckbeard's answer in this QA](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg).

```
melt -verbose \
Screenshot_20180514-172311.png out=50 \
Screenshot_20180514-172231.png out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
Screenshot_20180514-172252.png out=75 -mix 25 -mixer luma \
-consumer avformat:anim.gif
```

This produces the video as intended, shown via SDL. However, no output is written to disk. This happens even if other formats are used, for example `x264` as per the linked QA above. Moving the `-consumer` argument to the top* has no effect.

How can I get `melt` to produce file output?

<sup>* I wondered if order of operators was important, as in `ffmpeg`</sup>

Comment: [Linking all past instances of this question for tracking purposes](https://superuser.com/questions/1374570/no-file-output-produced-by-melt)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1374564/no-file-output-produced-by-melt)