# No output pad can be associated to link label '1:v'

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using this code but the error always come with.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i 0.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]\
[1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1];\
[2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2];\
[3:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3];\
[4:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4];\
[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" transition2.mp4
```

Error:

> `No output pad can be associated to link label '1:v'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon (`;`) after `[v0]` at the end of the third line. I've tested the fixed command with my PNGs and it's OK.

For the record, the fixed command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i 0.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0];\
[1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1];\
[2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2];\
[3:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3];\
[4:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4];\
[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" transition2.mp4
```

Comment: Now ,getting this error .     [Parsed_concat_9 @ 0x217f680] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 460x426, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (361x400, SAR 0:1)
[Parsed_concat_9 @ 0x217f680] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_9
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Can you please guide me on this , i want to take multiple images and apply fade in/out effect.Please guide me. @Kamil Maciorowski

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 I *guess* the tool complains about different resolutions of the video streams. Resize your PNGs to the same size beforehand. If it doesn't work, please post a separate question. Sticking to a single user and/or introducing new problem(s) in comments is not a good practice here. Let the entire community see your *new* problem. This is how the site works: one problem -- one question.

Comment: @ahmadlatif1084 See the example "For input images with varying or arbitrary sizes" in [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski okay checking it.