# Convert Fade In-out Transition to Crossfade with concating Video in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I refer this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/834035/1024261) for concating videos with fade in-out Transition.
But for CrossFade it was not doing any concate function.

#### Fade in Fade out Transition code

```
[-y,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114210.mp4,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/MP4_20190220_114036.mp4,
 -i, /storage/emulated/0/Received/VID-20190407-WA0001.mp4,
 -filter_complex, 
 [0:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih),pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1,fade=t=out:st=22.958:d=0.5[v0];
 [1:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih),pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=37.208:d=0.5[v1];
 [2:v]scale=iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih),pad=480:480:(480-iw*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(480/iw\,480/ih))/2,setsar=1:1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=16.846:d=0.5[v2];

 [v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vTemp][aTemp],
 -map, [vTemp], -map, [aTemp],
 -vcodec, mpeg4, -shortest, -preset, ultrafast, 
 /storage/emulated/0/Video/Video_1563274780403.mp4]
```

> I need to convert this code to **crossfade** Transition

How to concate this videos with Crossfade Transition

Your help would be appretiated.