# FFMPEG - if yuv420p pixel format is deprecated, which one is newer and recommended?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running [this](https://superuser.com/a/834035/588467) script and I get this warning: "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly using ffmpeg"

If the pixel format yuv420p is deprecated, which one is newer and better and recommended to be used?

Comment: I know it's a warning and not an error, I know there is nothing to fix. Yet, if the format is deprecated, maybe there exists a newer and better one?

Comment: The overall format is not deprecated, having individual switches (`yuv420p` and `yuvj420p`) for limited and full-range colour spaces is deprecated and the warning is telling you to make sure you have specified the range so that it knows how to set up the colour space.

Comment: And then what kind of switches for limited and full-range colour spaces are not deprecated?

Comment: The switches are not deprecated. Use the `scale` filter with `in_range` and `out_range`.

Comment: @slhck still the same warning, nothing changed

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, it probably won't change. The word "deprecated" is maybe misleading here.