# I can't change the resolution on handbrake

Tags: resolution, handbrake

I want to resize a video from 708x1080 to 640x1136 but the resolution won't go above 1080

https://i.imgur.com/KUbGrUE.mp4

Comment: Your video would look distorted with that change, stretched vertically, squished horizontally.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I want it to add black bars

Comment: It doesn't add black bars automatically. That would be great but that's not how it works.

Comment: You're not upscaling, but the command should be about the same: https://superuser.com/questions/891145/ffmpeg-upscale-and-letterbox-a-video/891478#891478

Answer (score 2):

In your description, you are upsizing (1080 -> 1136) and downsizing (708 -> 640). This will change your aspect ratio and may make the output video look squished. Also 640 x 1136 (w x h) indicates a vertical capture such as from a smart phone (portrait mode). If this is not the case, be sure to match the proper numbers to the scaled dimensions (step 6 below).

Here's how to stretch a video any way you like:

1. Make sure you are using a recent version of HandBrake
2. With the video loaded, select your desired preset.
3. Switch to the Dimensions tab.
4. Set Resolution Limit = None
5. Set Anamorphic = Automatic
6. Check Allow Upscaling
7. Change Scaled Size to the desired dimensions width x height. Don't worry that the Pixel Aspect changes.
8. If you are trying to change the storage dimensions (Storage Aspect Ratio=SAR) but keep the display aspect (DAR) as it was, then keep Final Dimensions: ... Automatic checked.
9. If you really do want it squished, then uncheck Automatic and change the display size (width) to be the same as your scaled size width.
10. Click the Preview button and then Live Preview for 30 seconds to see if this is what you want. If not, readjust your specs and preview again.