# Error while merging two mp4 video files with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have few mp4 video files that i wants to merge them.

I am using this commands to convert .mp4 to .ts and then merge them together. [referance](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

```
ffmpeg -i part1.mp4  -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y part1.ts # executes successfully

ffmpeg -i part2.mp4  -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -y part2.ts # executes successfully

ffmpeg -i "concat:part1.ts|part2.ts"  -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -y full.mp4 # Error
```

Error:(but execution still continues)
input packets too small error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #0:1 
past duration 0.999992 too large

it take more than hours to do merging of 2 files which it doesn't take with other video files ( i think there is problem with part2.mp4 but don't know how to solve it )

Here is video info

**part1.mp4**

```
 C:\Users\JAGZ\Desktop\vid>ffmpeg -i part1.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-b
zlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcac
a --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr
--enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --e
nable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'part1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.104
  Duration: 00:00:07.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2355 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 128:117 DAR 160:117], 2034 kb/s, 25 fps, 2
5 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

**part2.mp4**

```
C:\Users\JAGZ\Desktop\vid>ffmpeg -i part2.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-b
zlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcac
a --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr
--enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --e
nable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 003075c0] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'part2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2016-03-07T16:01:20.000000Z
    title           : 2006/14 Coke Crisis
    media_type      : 9
    network         : A/V Input
    date            : 2016-03-07
    iTunMOVI        : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    : <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
                    : <plist version="1.0">
                    : <dict>
                    :   <key>asset-info</key>
                    :   <dict>
                    :           <key>file-size</key>
                    :           <integer>837215671</integer>
                    :           <key>flavor</key>
                    :           <string>4:640x480</string>
                    :           <key>high-definition</key>
                    :           <false/>
                    :           <key>screen-format</key>
                    :           <string>standard</string>
                    :           <key>soundtrack</key>
                    :           <string>LC</string>
                    :   </dict>
                    :   <key>cast</key>
                    :   <array/>
                    :   <key>codirectors</key>
                    :   <array/>
                    :   <key>copy-warning</key>
                    :   <string></string>
                    :   <key>directors</key>
                    :   <array/>
                    :   <key>producers</key>
                    :   <array/>
                    :   <key>screenwriters</key>
                    :   <array/>
                    :   <key>studio</key>
                    :   <string></string>
                    : </dict>
                    : </plist>
                    :
  Duration: 01:09:03.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1616 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1485 kb/s, 24.99 fps, 25 tbr, 25k
 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-07T16:01:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : H.264/AVC
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-07T16:01:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 512x748 [SAR 72:72 DAR 128:187], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

can someone suggest me what change do i make in command to merge this videos  ?

Comment: Please provide the full, uncut command line output from your first three commands.

Comment: @slhck updated details with full output

Comment: You cannot join these two files without reencoding. They have different H264 profiles and different resolution.

Comment: @DanielB It's technically possible to join them but the output will not look as expected or may not play.

Comment: @JAGGADAKU I asked about the output of the three commands you were running, not the output of `ffmpeg -i part1.mp4`. (You need to disable `-v quiet`.)

Comment: @DanielB  i am able to convert to .ts and then merge (both to .ts) but when i tries to convert it back to mp4 it shows many errors

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your input: Your input videos have different frame dimensions (720×576 vs. 640×480). In such a case you cannot just concatenate the raw bitstreams. Well, you can, but then the playback will not support switching the resolution – it will just show at the resolution of your first input video, or may crash some players.

Instead, you should probably decode the videos and bring them to a common format (frame dimensions, frame rate, color space, pixel aspect ratio, …), then re-encode them.

The above can be achieved with the `concat` filter, but first, you have to scale/pad either one of those inputs, e.g. by upscaling `part2.mp4` to 720×576 (with padding):

```
ffmpeg -i part1.mp4 -i part2.mp4 -filter_complex "\
[0:v]setsar=1[0v]; \
[1:v]scale=720:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=1,\
     pad=720:576:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[1v]; \
[0v][0:a][1v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] \
" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
output.mp4
```

See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player) and the [FFmpeg Wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) for more info on scaling and concatenating. And read the [H.264 encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) on how to set the quality for the output.

Comment: Thank you for response......but above command says `No such filter: 'force_original_aspect_ratio'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument` i am running windows

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, please try again.

Comment: `[Parsed_concat_2 @ 04930620] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 720x576, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 paramet
ers (720x576, SAR 128:117)
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 04930620] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_2
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument`
Now this is problem........i am sorry but i don't have any idea about how this filter complex works

Comment: True, the pixel aspect ratios are different for the two files as well, so you need to change that to 1 as well. The complex filter is a little complicated to understand, yeah. Providing your input files and the requested output would (have) help(ed).

Comment: another question. I already have libx264 enabled on my ffmpeg then why it says that `[NULL @ 047eb220] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libx264'
libx264: Invalid argument`

Comment: Then you're using a wrong command line option. If you want x264 as codec, you need `-c:v libx264`.