# using ffmpeg on both landscape and portait pics

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i port001.jpg -vf "scale=100:-1" /tmp/1/port_converted_100-1.jpg
```

It is working fine on landscape pics but it automatically rotate the portrait pics.
Any idea how to avoid the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

## The exif *Orientation* tag is ignored by `ffmpeg`

This is ticket [#6945: ffmpeg fails at jpeg EXIF orientation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6945).

---

### Rotate your images before using `ffmpeg`*

#### Manually

`jpegtran` can be used to losslessly rotate images. You can use it manually to rotate or create a script to rotate based on the Orientation tag.

```
jpegtran -rotate 90 input.jpg > output.jpg
```

Note that this will strip some of the exif data. If you want to keep it all add `-copy all` then remove the now incorrect Orientation tag with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -Orientation="" output.jpg
```

#### With `exifautotran`

This tool with automatically re-orient the images according to the Orientation tag:

```
mkdir images
cp *.jpg images
cd images
exifautotran *.jpg
```

<sub>* If ticket #6945 is fixed then this method will become moot.</sub>

### Viewing exif orientation tag in JPG image

You can use `exiftool` to view the orientation:

```
$ exiftool -Orientation -S image.jpg
  Orientation: Rotate 90 CW
$ exiftool -Orientation -n -S image.jpg
  Orientation: 6
```

---

### Now you can scale with `ffmpeg`

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "scale=100:-1" output
```

For more fancy scaling see [Resizing images with ffmpeg to fit into specific sized box](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524).

Comment: Is there any way to know the pic orientation? If there is not, this solution doesn't fit my needs as I don't know in advance what will be the pic orientation. 
I'm provising service to re-scale any pic no mater what is the orientation.

Comment: @Benny I added some examples of viewing the Orientation tag with `exiftool`. Or just use `exifautotran` as mentioned before and you won't have to worry about Orientation.