# FFMPEG need help to optimize the command

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm doing multiple operations with FFMPEG.
I have 5 files.

1. intro_image.jpg: This is an image of any resolution but will be jpeg.
2. intro_audio.mp3: This audio is static input of duration 7 seconds.
3. outro_image.jpg: This is an image of any resolution but will be jpeg.
4. outro_audio.mp3: This audio is static input of duration 7 seconds.
5. user_video.mp4: User video can be of any resolution but a minimum 480P and of any format like mp4, avi, mkv. the maximum duration of the video will be 1 minute only.

What I'm doing is merging all the videos in 480P with a black background.

Step 1: Merging intro_image.jpg and intro_audio.mp3 to create intro_video.mp4

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i #{params[:intro_image].path} -i #{params[:intro_audio].path} -vf 'scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest #{dir}/#{intro_video_name}
```

Step 2: Merging outro_image.jpg and outro_audio.mp3 to create outro_video.mp4

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i #{params[:outro_image].path} -i #{params[:outro_audio].path} -vf 'scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest #{dir}/#{outro_video_name}
```

Step 3: I check if audio is avaiable in the `user_video.mp4`. if not then:

```
ffmpeg -i #{params[:video].path} -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest  #{video_path}
```

Step 4: Trim users video according to the provided `start_time` & `end_time`.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

Step 5: Merge all three videos.

```
ffmpeg -y -i #{dir}/#{intro_video_name} -i #{video_path} -i #{dir}/#{outro_video_name} -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=640x480,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]scale=640x480,setsar=1[v2];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1' -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast -vsync vfr #{dir}/#{final_video_name}
```

all these steps take around 40 seconds if the total file size is 10 MB. I'm looking for a way to optimize these commands without losing video quality.

Comment: It can be done in 1 command, but need more info about your inputs. Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -n -i intro_image.jpg -i intro_audio.mp3 -i outro_image.jpg -i outro_audio.mp3 -i user_video.mp4`. How long is the average user video? Is user video always going to be the same format and have the same attributes, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: @llogan Thank you for the comment, I've edited the post.

Comment: user's video can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper concatenation all inputs must have the same attributes, so use multiple filters to make them all the same before concatenation:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 7 -framerate 25 -i intro_image.jpg -i intro_audio.mp3 -loop 1 -t 7 -framerate 25 -i outro_image.jpg -i outro_audio.mp3 -i user_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black,format=yuv420p,setsar=1[introv];[2:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black,format=yuv420p,setsar=1[outrov];[4:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black,format=yuv420p,fps=25,setsar=1[userv];[1:a]aformat=r=44100:cl=stereo[introa];[4:a]aformat=r=44100:cl=stereo[usera];[3:a]aformat=r=44100:cl=stereo[outroa];[introv][introa][userv][usera][outrov][outroa]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black` - [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) filters to make image/video fit into 640x480 as shown in [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/)
- `format=yuv420p` - [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to make chroma subsampling the same. Alternatively you can use just one instance of format filter on the output from concat.
- `setsar=1` - [setsar](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setsar) filter to make aspect ratio the same. concat filter requires all segments to have the same aspect ratio.
- `fps=25` - [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) filter to set frame rate of the user video to match the frame rate of the images. Because your inputs are arbitrary you need to use fps filter to set a specific frame rate.
- `aformat=r=44100:cl=stereo` - [aformat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) filter to make all audio have the same sample rate and channel layout.
- `[introv][introa][userv][usera][outrov][outroa]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]` [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) filter to concatenate/join all of the segments into a single output.

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain a little bit.

Comment: @JasjeetSingh See updated answer.

Comment: I tried but ran into a scenario where the command fails. when I use a silent video it gives an error.

Comment: @JasjeetSingh What is the error?