# Resize images and fit into frames in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, size

I want to resize several images of different sizes.
I need to fit it all into the frame.
But it completely fill the height or width. Pixels are all saved.
Maintaining proportions. Increase or decrease is not important. Is it possible?
[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoTki.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1136305/ may do what you're looking for, but it's difficult to understand what you want to do.